# Are these chinese characters understandable?

Tags: character-identification

I am designing a logo for my company, starting from a chinese word (which i am not mentioning not to influence you, i am including it below in a spoiler).

I simplified the ideograms a lot and I wonder if in the process the original meaning was lost:

[image: logo from chinese word]

- Are both versions undestandable?
- The second version, the vertical lower one, is very simplified, would a Chinese person be able to read it?
- Is that little stroke on top of the first character needed or can i remove it? It triggers my OCD

The solution to the enigma is down here, if possible answer with a spoiler not to influence other commenters!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is plain as day that the two characters in both version of the logo are 烏黑 (pitch-black)in native Chinese's eyes.

The top stroke of 烏 doesn't need to touch the frame, but you can't remove it if you want the character to remain legit.

Invert the color can make it stand out more

You have the option of reducing the four dots at the bottom of both 烏 and 黑 to one straight stroke. That make it more abstract looking. (*native Chinese would take a second to recognize the characters, but they will recognize them no doubt*)

[image]

(I was a graphic designer too, I suggest you try different fonts to get different feel. Your current design is basically a seal. I am sure you have more different concepts)

Comment: Thank you for the one straight line suggestion (which will make them more similar to their Simplified Chinese counterparts, i assume).

The logo will be probably white on black (on a  micro chip) but I normally design as black on white pixels, helps me making things more even and simple. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Both designs are recognisable. However, for the first one, the "layout" of individual strokes is, IMO, unacceptable for your purpose.

The first stroke (the dot) of the first character **cannot** be omitted.

Lastly, although it's recognisable, I would suggest you try, using clerical script, bronze script, or small seal script (in sequence) for company logo.

Have fun :)

Comment: thank you very much, i will look into the scripts

what is unacceptable for my purpose in the first layout?

Comment: the second character "黑", the bottom component (four dots) is too large, then, the top component (网, or letter 四) is too narrow. it's unpleasant.